# Question about Godel's 2nd Theorem

Tags: lo.logic

Let Con(PA) be the sentence of arithmetic which translates as "Peano Arithmetic is consistent." Then according to Godel's 2nd incompleteness theorem, assuming PA is consistent then PA can neither prove Con(PA) nor its negation. And in fact, if T contains PA and T is (omega-) consistent, then T can neither prove Con(T) nor its negation. In particular, if PA+Con(PA) is consistent then PA+Con(PA) can neither prove Con(PA+Con(PA)) nor its negation.

But consider the following piece of reasoning: if PA is consistent, then Con(PA) is true, so PA+Con(PA) is consistent, so Con(PA+Con(PA)) is true. My question is, why can't this reasoning by formalized in PA, so that within PA you can prove Con(PA) implies Con(PA+Con(PA))? If you could prove that, then since you can obviously prove Con(PA) within PA+Con(PA), you would be able to prove Con(PA+Con(PA)) within PA+Con(PA), which is a contradiction. So where am I going wrong?

We can even talk about this in terms of model theory. There are nonstandard models of PA in which Con(PA) does not hold: basically, you have infinitely large natural numbers, and infinitely long proofs of a contradiction in PA. This does not mean that PA is inconsistent, because there are no proofs of finite length of this contradiction. So are there also nonstandard models of PA+Con(PA) in which Con(PA+Con(PA)) does not hold?  (That's a rhetorical question; clearly there must be, but what do they look like?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Doesn't the statement "if T contains PA and T is (omega-) consistent, then T can neither prove Con(T) nor its negation." require that T be computable? 

Comment: Quinn, we are of course talking about recursively axiomatized theories, so yes T is "computable."

Answer (score 5):

Here's a somewhat more detailed version of Ricky Demer's answer.

In the first sentence of your piece of reasoning, you say "if PA is consistent, then Con(PA) is true, so PA+Con(PA) is consistent".  The most natural justification for the step from "PA consistent and Con(PA) true" to "PA+Con(PA) consistent" presupposes that PA is true.  After all, a consistent but false theory could become inconsistent when some true statement is added to it.  So formalizing your argument would require proving that PA is true; that can't be done in PA --- in fact, "PA is true" can't even be expressed in the language of PA.

A more subtle justification for the step to "PA+Con(PA) is consistent" would use not the truth of PA but the weaker statement that all $\Sigma^0_1$ sentences provable in PA are true.  That can be expressed in the language of PA, but alas it's not provable in PA.  So the argument still can't be formalized in PA.

Comment: All right, what if we replaced every occurrence of the word "consistent" in my original post with the phrase "sigma-1 sound", and we replaced Con(T) with Sig(T), a statement of arithmetic saying "T is sigma-1 sound."  In that case what would be my error?   

Comment: Your error would be explained by doing the same replacements to my answer. $\hspace{1 in}$

Comment: Ricky, your answer was "You can't carry that out in PA because it could be that PA is consistent and proves ¬Con(PA)."  But is it possible for PA to be sigma-1 sound and prove ¬Sig(PA)? 

Comment: Yes. $\;$ (The only way I know to show that is from Godel's 2nd Thm.) $\;\;$

Comment: First of all, is the sentence Sig(PA) sigma-1?

Comment: @Keshav: No, it is $\Pi^0_2$ (and this is an optimal classification, as it is not contained in any consistent extension of PA by a set of $\Sigma^0_2$-sentences). By the way, the standard name of this statement is the uniform $\Sigma^0_1$-reflection principle, and it is denoted as $\mathrm{RFN}_T(\Sigma^0_1)$, $\mathrm{RFN}_{\Sigma^0_1}(T)$ or similar variations in the literature.

Comment: I mean, $T$ is PA in this particular case.

Comment: OK, is there any class C of arithmetic sentences such that C-soundness is definable within C?  In other words, the statement of arithmetic which translates as "T is C-sound" would itself be a C-sentence.  Or do Berry's-Paradox considerations rule out the existence of such a class?

Comment: $C=\Pi^0_n$ works for any $n>0$.

Comment: OK, then is it possible for a theory of arithmetic T to be Pi-1 sound but prove the negation of PI(T), the sentence of arithmetic which translates as "T is Pi-1 sound"?  It seems like this would be impossible, in which case my reasoning in my original post would work if we changed the word "consistent" to "Pi-1 sound".  Where is my error now?

Comment: $\Pi^0_1$-soundness is in fact equivalent to consistency (if $T$ proves a false $\Pi^0_1$-sentence $\phi$, then $\neg\phi$ is a true $\Sigma^0_1$-sentence, hence it is provable in $Q$, and a fortiori in $T$, hence $T$ is inconsistent). So, yes, there are $\Pi^0_1$-sound theories (for example, $\mathrm{PA}+\neg\mathrm{Con}(\mathrm{PA})$ that prove their own $\Pi^0_1$-unsoundness. Replacing $1$ with larger $n$ does not change this either. Your error might be this: the statement of $\Pi^0_n$-soundness is $\Pi^0_n$, but its *negation* is $\Sigma^0_n$. ...

Comment: ... Thus, even if a $\Pi^0_n$-sound theory proves the negation, it does not follow that the negation is true (which would give a contradiction). You’d need the theory to be $\Sigma^0_n$-sound to make this argument work, which is a stronger assumption ($\Sigma^0_n$-soundness is equivalent to $\Pi^0_{n+1}$-soundness).

Answer (score 3):

You can't carry that out in PA because it could be that PA is consistent and proves $\lnot$Con(PA).

(in which case PA is not $\omega$-consistent)

The best description of a model "of PA+Con(PA) in which Con(PA+Con(PA)) does not hold" would be

"Take the standard model of PA, then 'insert' a nonstandard natural coding a proof of $\lnot$Con(PA)".